# Group binary operation symbol?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I tried to write • as the binary operation for a group (G, •), but `\cdot` seems too small and `\bullet` seems too large, so what symbol is normally used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it's just `\cdot`, it's what people are used to and it doesn't look small in `$(G,{\cdot})$` to me.

Anyway, if you want a bigger dot, you can load the package `\usepackage{bm}` *after any other font package*, and then define `\newcommand\bigcdot{\bm{\cdot}}` and use this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of topic, audience, and personal taste. For a group operation consider an asymmetric binary symbol like \oslash, though perhaps not arrow-like symbols like \triangleright  which suggests a mapping. But if \oslash is commonly associated with another operation in your field, then another asymmetric symbol could be used. For an abelian group operation consider a more symmetric symbol like \cdot, \ast, \bullet, etc..

There is no right way unless you are working under house rules, but it can be helpful to have symbols that graphically suggest properties (e.g. asymmetry) or avoid suggesting properties not assumed (e.g. commutativity).

Consider including

```
\newcommand\gop{\mathbin{\oslash}}
```

Then you can use a\gop b and modify globally ad lib.